# Como obtener una lista ordenada que incluya 2 listas de distinto tamaño

Tags: java, eclipse

Debe ser estrictamente en Iterativo

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(5);
    list.add(7);
    list.add(2);

    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list2.add(3);
    list2.add(6);
    list2.add(4);
    list2.add(1);

    System.out.println(cadenaOrdenadaIt(list, list2));
    //System.out.println(cadenaOrdenadaJ10(list, list2));
    //System.out.println(cadenaOrdenadaRecLF(list, list2));
}

public static SortedSet<Integer> cadenaOrdenadaIt(List<Integer> l1, List<Integer> l2){

    SortedSet<Integer> s = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    int i = 0;

    while(l1.size() != i || l2.size() != i){
        if(l1.get(i) <= l2.get(i)) {
            s.add(l1.get(i));
            s.add(l2.get(i));
            i = i + 1;
        }else {
            s.add(l2.get(i));
            s.add(l1.get(i));
            i = i + 1;
        }
    }
    if(l1.isEmpty()) {
        s.addAll(l2);
    }
    if(l2.isEmpty()) {
        s.addAll(l1);
    }

    return s;
}
```

[image: Consola]

Comment: Hola Manuel. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Has de pulsar en [edit] para mejorar la pregunta añadiendo informacion que necesitamos para ayudarte. Explica mejor lo que te propones y por qué ahora mismo el programa no hace lo que quieres. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. Un saludo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No entiendo qué quieres decir con iterativo, pero una opción es:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(5);
    list.add(7);
    list.add(2);

    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list2.add(3);
    list2.add(6);
    list2.add(4);
    list2.add(1);

    List<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list3.addAll(list);
    list3.addAll(list2);
    Collections.sort(list3);

    System.out.println(list3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ya lo he solucionado. Lo dejo por aquí por si a alguien le sirve.

```
public static SortedSet<Integer> cadenaOrdenadaIt(List<Integer> l1, List<Integer> l2){

    SortedSet<Integer> s = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    int i = 0;
    if(0==l1.size() ) {
        s.addAll(l2);
    }
    if(0==l2.size()) {
        s.addAll(l1);
    }
    while(l1.size() != i && l2.size() != i){
        if(l1.get(i) < l2.get(i)) {
            s.add(l1.get(i));
            s.add(l2.get(i));
            i = i + 1;
        }
        if(l2.get(i) < l1.get(i)) {
            s.add(l2.get(i));
            s.add(l1.get(i));
            i = i + 1;
        }
        if(i == l1.size() ) {
            s.addAll(l2);
            break;
        }
        if(i == l2.size() ) {
            s.addAll(l1);
            break;
        }
    }

    return s;
}
```